# Merge [r.net] and [rdotnet]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[r.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.net) and [rdotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdotnet) refer to the same library and should be merged. Each has slightly fewer than 100 questions, and a fair few of these carry both tags.

[rdotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdotnet) has slightly more questions but I don’t know whether there’s a “canonical” tag naming style that makes one more appropriate than the other. [The actual library itself](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet) uses both stylings (“R.NET” and “rdotnet”).

Answer (score 7):

I agree this is a good idea. With the help of the magical unicorn powers bestowed upon me, this merge and synonym mapping is now live on a Stack Overflow near you:

### [r.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.net) ← [rdotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdotnet)

I also wasn't sure which variant of the name to pick as the "master" tag. I arbitrarily chose [r.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r.net) because that looks nicer and more readable to me. If someone has a compelling reason that I should reconsider, please let me know.